# For loop starts with "c" instead of "d"

Tags: python, for-loop, reverse

```
   s="abcd" 
   for i in range(len(s)-1)[::-1]: 
        print(s[i])
```

I cannot understand how this for loop works ?

Comment: `range` excludes the end, so `range(len(s))` is `0, 1, 2`.

Comment: notice the minus 1 in `len(s)-1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**class range(start, stop[, step])**

The range type represents an immutable sequence of numbers and is commonly used for looping a specific number of times in for loops. (taken from python docs).

for further reading go to python docs : [range](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#range)

After reading the above (taken from python docs) and printing the expression: `range(len(s)-1)[::-1]`,

```
print(range(len(s)-1)[::-1])
```

which yields:

```
range(2, -1, -1)
```

so our code becoms:

```
   s="abcd" 
   for i in range(2, -1, -1): 
        print(s[i])
```

And now i hope you understand what python does behind the scenes!

Answer (score 0):

so your range goes from 0 to 2 `(len(s)-1) - 1` but `[::-1]` reverses whatever is sent by range.

So your loop goes from 2 to 1 to 0

`s = "abcd"`

```
for 2 > it prints c
for 1 > it prints b
for 0 > it prints a
```

if you want to start from d:

```
s="abcd" 
for i in range(len(s))[::-1]: 
    print(s[i])
```

Comment: Does "i" start from 0 or len(s)-1

Answer (score 0):

This is because your range is converted as `range(2, -1, -1)`. You just need to remove -1 from `range (len(s) -1)[::-1]`.

Comment: So i  starts from len(s)-1 in this case or does I start from 0 and the string is reversed?

Comment: No you should replace range(len(s) -1)[::-1] with range(len (s))[::-1].

Answer (score 0):

For `s="abcd"` we have `len(s)-1` equals `3`.

`range(3)` generates `(0, 1, 2)`.

`(0, 1, 2)[::-1]` results in `(2, 1, 0)`.

So the for loop will print `s[i]` for `i` in `(2, 1, 0)`, resulting in `cba`.